# How to animated a UIImageView smoothly in swift with AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview

I'm trying to replicate the animation of an app I currently use. In the app, after a picture is taken, if the user taps the `UIImageView`, it smoothly expands to a certain size, and upon tapping the `UIImageView`, it smoothly collapses to the original size.

Here is an example:

[image]

However, when I tried to replicate it, the animation is "wooply" as seen here:

[image]

Here's my code sample:

```
if recogizer.view == thumbnailImageView && isThumbnailExpanded == false
{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {() -> Void in

    self.thumbnailImageView!.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width * 0.7
    self.thumbnailImageView!.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height * 0.6
    self.thumbnailImageView!.frame.origin.x = (self.view.frame.width / 2) - (self.thumbnailImageView!.frame.size.width / 2)
    self.thumbnailImageView!.frame.origin.y = -100

    })

    isThumbnailExpanded = true
    }
else if recogizer.view == thumbnailImageView && isThumbnailExpanded == true
{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {() -> Void in

    self.thumbnailImageView!.frame.size.width = self.thumbnailImageViewWidth
    self.thumbnailImageView!.frame.size.height = self.thumbnailImageViewHeight
    self.thumbnailImageView!.frame.origin.x = self.thumbnailImageViewXPosition
    self.thumbnailImageView!.frame.origin.y = self.thumbnailImageViewYPosition

    })

    isThumbnailExpanded = false
}
```

Here's my autolayout constraints:

[image]
How can I animate my `UIImageView` more smoothly as seen in above?

Thanks

Comment: Check auto layout constraint or post the snap of it

Comment: Post the size class property snap from the size inspector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The animation appears wobbly because you are changing the image's aspect ratio, you should maintain the aspect ratio so as not to squish the image.

---

Also, you should not animate a auto layout constraint-based `UIView` by changing its frame. Inside the animation block, you should change the image view constraints you added in the storyboard.

To get a reference to your storyboard created constraints, create an IBOutlet by <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging them to your view controller. This will create a variable of type `NSLayoutConstraint` in your code. Inside the animation block, change the `constant` property of each constraint you want to change and then call `layoutIfNeeded` on the view.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {

    yourConstraint.constant = 20
    // any other constraints...
    // ...
    thumbnailImageView.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't come to that due to the fact that I have to change the constant for each device screen. Is this the only way to deal with this auto-layout issue?

Comment: You shouldn't change the constant on a per-device basis, you should just modify the multiplier of the proportional with constraint.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand..??...the proportional height multiplier has already been modified in storyboard...example please?

Comment: I had a typo in my previous comment, should be *width* instead of *with*. I'll try to explain better. You have the width of your image view related by a proportional width constraint to the width of the main view. It's default multiplier was maybe `0.5`. You should modify this multiplier to `0.8` inside your animation block, for example.

Comment: I have adjusted the constraints instead as suggested within `animateWithDuration`, however the animation is too fast, in fact it's instant as soon as I tapped the `UImageView`. Adjusted the duration time has no effect.

Comment: Fixed.it actually should be `view.layoutIfNeeded()`...this will provide the `UIImageView` with the appropriate animated speed